# Calculating direction of polygon using other features? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2

In QGIS 2 or 3 I have some DEM rasters, on top of that vector layers with plots and buildings + pin (blue one) with coordinates of building.

How to calculate position of garden? Is it n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw? In this case it should return of course: East.

Suppose I can calculate distance from blue pin to all corners of shape (which might be more complicated), choose 2 the longest distances and then somehow calculate direction?

How to do that feature-by-feature? In this case feature means pink plot.

[image: Plots with buildings]

Comment: is there an unique attribute relation between either the pins or building polygons to the parcels? naive approach: the inverse direction of the pins (or building centroids) from the centroids of their parcel polygon. generalize that direction over circle quadrants/octants to get the general compass direction.

Comment: Yes, plots, pins, and footprints have the same house_id. Now I've caluclated centroids, but have problem how to bind correctly two layers to calculate azimuth